# How to update a pull request by GitHub APP API?

Tags: node.js, github-api, github-app

I developed GitHub APP to manage pull requests process, I'm using two APIs
1. [statuses check API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statuses/)
2. [update-a-pull-request API](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#update-a-pull-request)
I get this error message when a request to update an existing pull request that was created by one of the users.

**How I can get installation token with the right permissions?**

```
{
  "message": "Validation Failed",
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Only the pull request author may change the maintainer_can_modify value",
      "resource": "PullRequest",
      "field": "maintainer_can_modify",
      "code": "invalid"
    }
  ],
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#update-a-pull-request"
}
```

To execute API call, I need token, I generated the token in this way:

- Created app in GitHub Account
- Created a private PEM key in the APP
- In code, created JWT token using PEM key
- Using the JWT token to create installation token as below

Header

```
function generateJwtToken() {
    return jsonwebtoken.sign(
        {
            iat: Math.floor(new Date() / 1000),
            exp: Math.floor(new Date() / 1000) + 60,
            iss: ISSUER_ID,
        },
        PEM,
        {algorithm: 'RS256'},
    );
}
let githubHeadersToAccessToken = {
    'User-Agent': 'nodejs',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + generateJwtToken(),
    'Accept': 'application/vnd.github.machine-man-preview+json'
};
```

Get Installation token

```
payloadToken = {
    "repository_ids": [
    ],
    "permissions": {
        "pull_requests": "write",
        "statuses": "write",
        "administration" : "write",
        "organization_administration": "write",
        "contents": "write",
        "team_discussions": "write",
    }
};
request.get({
    url: 'https://api.github.com/app/installations',
    headers: githubHeadersToAccessToken
}, function optionalCallback(err, httpResponse, body) {
    if (err) {
        return console.error('Connected App get token failed:', err);
    }
    console.log('APP Installation id');
    console.log('Installation id: ' + JSON.parse(body)[0].id);
    app_installed_id = JSON.parse(body)[0].id;

    request.post({
        url: 'https://api.github.com/app/installations/'+app_installed_id+'/access_tokens',
        headers: githubHeadersToAccessToken,
        json: payloadToken
    }, function optionalCallback(err, httpResponse, body) {
        if (err) {
            return console.error('Failed to get access token to GitHub: ', err);
        }
        //console.log(body);
        console.log('Access token to GitHub: ' + body.token);
    });
});
```

Update existind pull request that was created by one of the users

```
   request.post({
        url: 'https://api.github.com/repos/'+owner+'/'+repo+'/statuses/'+sha,
        headers: githubHeadersApiV3,
        json: {
            "state": status,
            "context": "PR <> GUS Validation"
        }
    }, function optionalCallback(err, httpResponse, body) {
        if (err) {
            return console.error('Connected App get token failed:', err);
        }
        //console.log(body);
        console.log('commit sha: ' + sha + ' updated with status: ' + status);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I want to update that the code is working, I can update pull request using Github APP.
The problem I mentioned happen when I try to change "maintainer_can_modify" in pull request, which is not allowed, only by owner, then I just removed it. 
But in my case I wanted to add comment, change title, etc ..

I will leave this question as an example for building GitHub app to update pull request using NodeJS.